# In VUE 2.0 JS , vue_i18n v8 I want to translate values in my scripts

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I want to be able to translate the values in my script in relation to the i18n plugin. For example, I have an array in data that I want to output in multiple languages

I have to keys in my json translate file such as this :

```
 in en.json I have these two values 
    "OneWay": " OneWay",
    "Roundtrip": "Roundtrip",

 and in a component I want to call them with a Array
```

```
  data: () => ({
    tripType: [
      { id: 1, title: "" },
      { id: 2, title: "" },
    ],
    selectedTripType: 1,
  }),
```

So I want to get multi language value to this array for made a v-for in my codes

```
  computed: {
     translateOneWay : function(){
     let OneWay =this.$t('OneWay');
     let Roundtrip =this.$t('Roundtrip');
     this.tripType.title[0] = OneWay ;
     this.tripType.title[1] = Roundtrip ;
     }

  },
```

That is my template codes :

```
                <div
                  class="form-check-inline"
                  v-for="item in tripType"
                  :key="item.id"
                >
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      class="form-check-input"
                      :value="item.id"
                      v-model="selectedTripType"
                      @change="getTripType"
                    />
                    <span class="radio-title pl-2">{{ item.title }}</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
```

Comment: As `tripType` is an array and `title` is a string, It should be `this.tripType[0].title` instead of `this.tripType.title`. Also, You can mutate `tripType` directly instead of creating a computed property.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal imho mutating tripType property directly is bad idea. They would need to watch for language changes and mutate the property when change happen. If they use computed property the Vue will do that for them.

Comment: Yes right, I think i did not phrase correctly, My meaning was to maintain the reactivity for arrays in `vue 2`, we have to set the whole array again instead of updating the index values.